# How to set debug=false while building a solution in teamcity

Tags: build, msbuild, teamcity, debug-symbols

I want to set debug=false while building a solution using msbuild in teamcity. Is there any parameter that I can pass so that while building in release mode it wont copy the debug symbols in bin directory. I tried using /p:debug=false but it didnt work. I don't want to use web config transformation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not generate the pdbs then you need to pass /p:DebugSymbols=false;DebugType=None commandline

Answer (score -1):

You can change the Advanced Build Settings in Visual Studio for Release build configuration.

Open project Properties, open Build tab. Press "Advanced..." button on bottom and change Debug info to "none".